# How to make Dynamic Spinner inside RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dynamic, spinner

I'm going to create a **Dynamic CardView** with these components such as **TextView** (*Item Name*), **Spinner** (*Activity Selection*) and **EditText** (*Static Remarks*).

I have already set/get the **Item Name** for every list in the array but for the **Spinner Item** I have encounter error.

Please see below for your reference. Thank you!

***1. FormActivity.java***

```
    private void buildRecyclerView() {
       mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_item); //RecyclerView
       mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mItemList, this);

       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

***mItemList*** that I am going to past to ***ItemAdapter.class***

```
{
        "item_id": 1,
        "location_id": 1,
        "item_name": "Credit Back Door",
        "value": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            ]
        }
    },

{
        "item_id": 2,
        "location_id": 1,
        "item_name": "2F Admin Bridgeway",
        "value": [
                "D",
                "E",
                "F"
            ]
        }
    }
```

***2. form_item.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/itemCard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:layout_gravity="fill"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
app:cardElevation="20dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="1. Item"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#327034"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dd_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_remarks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:hint="Remarks"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

***2.2 Dynamic CardView UI***
[Please click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIcrM.png)

***3. ItemAdapter.java***

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
public ArrayList<ItemParams> mItemList;
public Context Context;

public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<ItemParams> itemList, Context context) {
    mItemList = itemList;
    Context = context;
}

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txt_item;
    public Spinner dd_activity;
    public EditText txt_remarks;
    public CardView itemCard;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCard);
        txt_item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item);
        dd_activity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dd_activity);
        txt_remarks = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_remarks);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.form_item, parent, false);
    ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder cvh = new ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder(v);

    //SPINNER ITEM SAMPLE BUT IT WILL BE A DYNAMIC FROM ONE OF THE LIST
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(parent.getContext(),R.layout.form_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    cvh.dd_activity.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    return cvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ItemParams mFormItem = mItemList.get(position);

    holder.txt_item.setText(mFormItem.getItem_name());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItemList.size();
}
```

}

Error:

```
2021-07-01 13:28:34.645 7337-7337/com.unilab.healthcheck E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

2021-07-01 13:28:35.050 7337-7337/com.unilab.healthcheck E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

2021-07-01 13:28:35.053 7337-7337/com.unilab.healthcheck E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.unilab.healthcheck, PID: 7337 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Comment: So, what is the error with the spinner?

Comment: Hmm, show the ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder class too, with the constructor.

Comment: You are creating the ItemViewHolder before the ArrayAdapter, this way the new ItemHolder will not have the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @Matheus please see the updated codes. Thank you!

Comment: @Zain please see the updated post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FormActivity.java**

```
private void buildRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_item); //RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(mItemList,getApplicationContext()));
    }
```

**ItemAdapter.java**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<ItemParams> mItemList;
    public Context context;

    public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<ItemParams> itemList, Context context) {
        this.mItemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txt_item;
        public Spinner dd_activity;
        public EditText txt_remarks;
        public CardView itemCard;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCard);
            txt_item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_item);
            dd_activity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dd_activity);
            txt_remarks = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_remarks);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.form_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //SPINNER ITEM SAMPLE BUT IT WILL BE A DYNAMIC FROM ONE OF THE LIST
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list 1");
        list.add("list 2");
        list.add("list 3");

        holder.dd_activity.setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list));

        holder.txt_item.setText(mItemList.get(position).getItem_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemList.size();
    }
    
}
```

But i believe that the error is in the xml:

> android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item

If the error still appear try to switch to a XML similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_dropdown_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="@string/texte"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you don't have to initialize array in the adapter instead you can make list in the activity or fragment whichever you have,
You can try this snippets(reference is from your code)

->First you have to add this code to activity or fragment

```
        //SPINNER ITEM SAMPLE
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list 1");
        list.add("list 2");
        list.add("list 3");
        recycleview.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity(),list));
```

-> Then

```
package com.brnd.pos.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<String> list;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.form_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(parent.getContext(), R.layout.form_item, R.id.dd_activity, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cvh.dd_activity.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        ItemParams mFormItem = mItemList.get(position);
        holder.txt_item.setText(mFormItem.getItem_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
         return list.size();
    }

    //below viewholder is just for your reference you have to find view id's
    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Follow up question, What if the value of the spinner item depends on the list that passed to ItemAdapter? Please see the updated post. Thank you once again.