# RecyclerView Spinner showing data for all the rows instead of only one row at a time

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, spinner

I have two spinners in my `RecyclerView`. My first spinner is filled inside of the xml ->

```
<Spinner
       android:id="@+id/itemspnReason"
       android:layout_width="600dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:entries="@array/list_reasons"
       />
```

How ever with my second spinner it is not so easy. The spinner will show a number between 1 and the quantity available per item showed in the `RecyclerView`. Currently I have this code inside my `onBindViewHolder` ->

```
val modal = partsList[position]
        holder.apply {
            var i = 1
            while (i <= modal.PQTY){ adapter.add(i.toString())
                i++}
            itemspnQTY.adapter = adapter
}
```

It works in getting to the desired number. The problem is each spinner is filled with all the data from each entry into the `RecyclerView`. For example if my first item had a size of 2 and my second item had a size of 4. Each of my spinner will contain the following: 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4.

So I need a way to clear the data after each entry or a better way to populate my spinner. My spinner is inside my `item_list.xml` for my `RecyclerView`. The easy solution is to do the same as my other spinner and create a static/hardcode entry. However I would like my spinner size to change based on how many items are available.

I have tried putting it inside my `onCreateViewHolder` and `init`. It did not solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I found help from a different post and implemented it with my app. ([How to make Dynamic Spinner inside RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203334/how-to-make-dynamic-spinner-inside-recyclerview))

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RowViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val modal = partsList[position]

         var i = 1
         val spnlist: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
   
             while (i <=  modal.PQTY){ spnlist.add(i)
                 i++}
         
         holder.itemspnQTY.adapter = 
                ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spnlist)
}
```